# expression engine jump to #id location on loaded page possible?

Tags: navigation

Just wondered if its possible to make a newly loaded page jump to a id ?
with or without javascript

like the old fasion way of having links to jump the same page. 
goto 4
would jump to 
jump here

Can this be archived on load ? if forexample my link is in segment_2

thats all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You'd just need something like this is in your template:

```
{if segment_2!=''}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.scrollTo('#{segment_2}');
})
</script>
{/if}
```

That's assuming you have some sort of "scrollTo" jQuery add-on. You'll have to check the validity of that quickly written code.

Comment: I'll do a check and return with an accept

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't be able to do it without JavaScript, unless you link directly to the anchor from the previous page.

```
<a href="{path='page-with-id'}#id">Page with ID</a>
```